# Calculating values from feature service without adding field to service

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am accessing an ArcGIS Online feature service where each day the values in the table are accumulating rather than displaying that day's data. This is not my feature service so I do not have editing access.
For example, in the example below the value for Day 2 is 5 and the value for Day 3 is 15.

Day 1 10
Day 2 15
Day 3 30

Is there a way to calculate these values in a ArcGIS Online web map or application without writing into the service?

Comment: It would be trivial to write a proxy filter to present this information, but no, you can't change someone else's service *in situ* without permission.

Comment: What is a proxy filter?

Comment: A proxy filter is a web application that accepts a request intended for another site, forwards the request to that site, then returns what the site returned, except for the part it modifies to meet some requirement

Comment: Thanks Vince. What technology is used to create these proxy filters? Are there any examples you could recommend to see in use now?

Comment: Java/JSP, C++/C# or even C can be used to write a filter. The logical flow for such filters is Listen1, Read1, Connect2, Write2, Read2, Close2, Write1, Listen1... (with zero, one, or more Manipulate operations somewhere between steps). There are likely *billions* of such filter uses every day, seamlessly making the Internet work (or not work, though that's another topic). Fully documented, a basic JSP filter servlet might use 30 lines of source  (tersely written, it could be under a dozen lines). Basic skill in network programming is required.